# Only return a row if result is unique

Tags: php, sql

I have a db table that looks like this:

```
product_tag_id | tag_id | product_id
      1            1          1
      2            1          2
      3            3          1
```

I have some php that's running a query in a foreach loop:

```
$product_tags = [1,3];
foreach(product_tags as $tag) {
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT product.*, product_tags.* FROM product
    INNER JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = product.product_id
    WHERE product_tags.tag_id =" . $tag);
}
```

The first query using 1 as the $tag value pulls in product_id 1 and 2 and the second query using 3 as $tag pulls in product_id 1 again.

I only want the query to return a row if it hasn't returned the product_id before. I only want to see a result if the product_id is unique. Is there any way to do this?

I thought DISTINCT would achieve this for me but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you really need all those columns?

Comment: Can you please add more sample data and provide your desired final result.  Is it MySql and PHP?

Comment: @ben:Do you mean, do I need to be selecting all those columns or do I really need all 3 of those columns in my db structure?

Comment: @Ben: no probably not but I just wanted to quickly write the query to get it working.

Comment: well .. if you want to select prodct_id only if it is unique then for tag_id = 1 also this will give only one product_id which is 2 .. will it be okay for you?

Comment: Ah group by looks like what I need but grouping by product_id does not work?!

Comment: Ok. Which tag do you want to "pull in" product 1? Do you want the greatest tag_id? The least tag_id? Something else? And what columns do you need to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you probably need a GROUP BY. I'm not really certain what the following actually means, you make it seem as though you have some sort of date column in the table.

> "I only want the query to return a row if it hasn't returned the product_id before."

I'm going to ignore this and assume that your current data is as follows and you have no additional columns to worry about:

```
product_tag_id | tag_id | product_id
      1            1          1
      2            1          2
      3            3          1
```

but you want to return this:

```
product_tag_id | tag_id | product_id
      1            1          1
      3            3          1
```

i.e. you want the minimum `PRODUCT_ID` per tag. So, you should select that:

```
SELECT pt.product_tag_id, pt.tag_id, min(p.product_id) as product_id
  FROM product
 INNER JOIN product_tags pt
    ON pt.product_id = p.product_id
 WHERE pt.tag_id = ?
 GROUP BY pt.product_tag_id, pt.tag_id
```

Comment: thanks - I've since realised the issue. This is basically what I was after but there was a problem with the question I was asking. See my comment on Mike's answer

Comment: @Mike, it's _always_ quicker to use the database than it is to use PHP. If you can do it in the database then do so.

Answer (score 1):

Including DDL in your question will *always* get you more and better answers.

```
create table products (
  product_id integer primary key,
  product_name varchar(15) unique
);

create table product_tags (
  product_tag_id integer primary key,
  tag_id integer not null,
  product_id integer not null,
  unique (tag_id, product_id)  
);

insert into products values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
insert into product_tags values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 3, 1);
```

> I only want the query to return a row if it hasn't returned the product_id before.

A different (and more useful) way to say this is "I want one row per product_id." To which we have to ask, "Then which tag_id do you want when there's more than one tag_id per product?"  Here, I return the minimum tag_id.

```
select products.product_id, products.product_name, tags.min_tag_id
from products
inner join 
    (select product_id, min(tag_id) min_tag_id
     from product_tags
     group by product_id) tags
  on tags.product_id = products.product_id
where tags.min_tag_id = 1
```

Comment: I see why my question was confusing now. I don't usually find it hard to articulate myself and write a clear question. I've since realised my problem but no one seemed to pick up on it. I'm running the query twice (there's a for each loop running in the code above) so what I was asking was never possible. The for each loop runs twice for the code above so there was no way to use mysql to limit the results. My boo...long day